# On Bootstrap Modal Close, clear all the rows of Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, bootstrap-modal

I am opening datatable in a Bootstrap Modal. It opens fine the first time but when I try and reopen the modal, instead of refreshing the data, it is just adding on to the existing data. Is there a way for me to clear the  tbody on modal close?

My HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-xl" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title text-left" id="modal_title"></h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" id="close_header" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div id="modal_content">
                                        <table id="modal_data"  class="display" border="1">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>One</th>
                                                    <th>Two</th>
                                                    <th>Three</th>
                                                    <th>Four</th>
                                                    <th>Five</th>
                                                    <th>Six</th>
                                                    <th>Seven</th>
                                                    <th>Eight Completes</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody></tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close_footer"data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JavaScript:

On Click of column in column chart (Highcharts):

```
events: {
          click: function() {
              let ver = this.series.name;
              getData(ver);
        }

 const getData = (v) => {
    $('#modal_title').text(v);
    $.getJSON(json, result => {
        result.forEach(d => {
            $("#modal_data>tbody").append(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${d.one}</td>
                    <td>${d.two}</td>
                    <td>${d.three}</td>
                    <td>${d.four}</td>
                    <td>${d.five}</td>
                    <td>${d.six}</td>
                    <td>${d.seven}</td>
                    <td>${d.eight}</td>
                </tr>
                `);

        });
        $('#modal_data').dataTable();
        $("#myModal").modal();
        $('#close_header, #close_footer').on('click', function() {
            $('#modal_data>tbody').dataTable().fnClearTable();
        });
    });
};
```

On close of the modal, I want to clear the table so that on column click it creates a fresh table of data rather than adding on to the old one.

Comment: Are you using https://datatables.net ?

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel, yes i am

Comment: For clarify as well, are you using bootstrap 4?

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel Yes I am

Comment: Please see my answer below & let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I tried a variation of all your solutions but this is what finally helped me.

Inside my click event:

```
events: {
      click: function() {
          $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
              $('#modal_data').DataTable().clear().draw();
              $('#modal_data').DataTable().destroy();
          });
          let ver = this.series.name;
          getData(ver);
    }
```

Appending rows and Declaration of my datatable

```
const getData = (v) => {
$('#modal_title').text(v);
$.getJSON(json, result => {
    result.forEach(d => {
        $("#modal_data>tbody").append(`
            <tr>
                <td>${d.one}</td>
                <td>${d.two}</td>
                <td>${d.three}</td>
                <td>${d.four}</td>
                <td>${d.five}</td>
                <td>${d.six}</td>
                <td>${d.seven}</td>
                <td>${d.eight}</td>
            </tr>
            `);

    });
    let table = $('#modal_data').dataTable();
    table = $('#modal_data').dataTable();
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding your clear event to the close buttons in the modal, you could make use of the bootstrap [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) to run your clear when the modal is no longer visibile.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("I've closed!");
});
```

Then based on the documentation for DataTables, you could use the [clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()) method to clear your table. You would need to re-draw your table once you have the data however, using the [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) method.

Personally, I'd use an approach like below.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var table = $('#modal_data').DataTable();
    table.clear();
});
```

You can then remove the on click event from your getData method. You will need to call the DataTable [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) method to re-render your table. 
There's likely a much more elegant way to re-bind your data and re-render the table using [rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()), but i think what I've put in here should be enough to solve your issue :)

```
const getData = (v) => {
    $('#modal_title').text(v);
    $.getJSON(json, result => {
        result.forEach(d => {
            $("#modal_data>tbody").append(`
                <tr>
                    <td>${d.one}</td>
                    <td>${d.two}</td>
                    <td>${d.three}</td>
                    <td>${d.four}</td>
                    <td>${d.five}</td>
                    <td>${d.six}</td>
                    <td>${d.seven}</td>
                    <td>${d.eight}</td>
                </tr>
                `);
        });
        var table = $('#modal_data').dataTable();
        table.destroy();
        table = $('#modal_data').dataTable();
        $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Comment: The `draw()` is throwing an error. I have put the `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal'... after the `getData` function. Is that correct or should it be before?

Comment: @noob you should place the `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal'` inside a window.onload or the [jquery equivalent](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @noob i've updated my answer with what i believe should now work based on the [datatables docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using `append`:

```
$("#modal_data>tbody").append(
```

`append()` means it will add (append) the rows to the last row every time. So instead of append you can use `html()`, this will clear the already existing rows and add the row. You can use it like:

```
$("#modal_data>tbody").html(
```

**Edit:** Declare a variable and store the html in it by using loop and pass that variable to `html()` function like:

```
var dynamHtml = '';
dynamHtml += 'your html here';
html(dynamHtml);
```

Comment: `.html` only adds one row

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close_footer">Close</button>

$('#close_header, #close_footer').on('click', function() {
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    $('#modal_data>tbody').empty();
);
```

Op's request:

> I want to clear the table

You can call the `empty()` jquery method to clear the contents of an element.

Comment: Its still adding to existing data :(

Comment: @noob please provide a snippet that reproduces your problem